# Flutter: How to show splash screen based on theme data saved using shared preferences?

Tags: flutter

Currently the splash screen is showed according to the device theme and rest of the app according to user selected theme, but I want to show the splash screen according to the selected theme by the user (which I do save in shared preferences).

Comment: There are some libraries that handle splash screens, if you use those you might be able to fetch the theme and then build it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

Splash screen is handled by the system, and you app isn't launched yet, so no code to load user preferences could be run.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, technically it's possible.

Here's a high-level overview:

You can always show a blank `Container()` on opening your app, while in the meantime you have your SharedPrefs checking the saved theme/appearance, then, once you have that data, you can show a splash screen where the rest of your prefs then load.

While at first glance this may seem inefficient, the call to SharedPrefs is *so fast* users literally won't notice that there was a frame of a blank screen before the Splash Screen comes up.

---

Source: Implemented this for my team's app and it works beautifully.